# Correct loading order of package newfloat along with hyperref and algorithmic packages?

Tags: hyperref, packages, minted, algorithmic, newfloat

There is extensive documentation that `hyperref` must be loaded towards the end. In particular, the following is the correct loading order for these specific packages:

```
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{algorithm}
```

Now, I have a slight complication. I am using the `minted` package with the option `newfloat=true`, i.e. using the `newfloat` package.

Does the loading order recommendation remain the same?, i.e.

```
\usepackage[newfloat=true]{minted}  % <-- Replacement for the float package?
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{algorithm}
```

or should I also additionally load the `float` package? (This doesn't sound right to me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [load order advice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1868/134641) is a bit confusing in this regard. It is, however, sufficient to load [`float`](https://ctan.org/pkg/float), before [`newfloat`](https://ctan.org/pkg/newfloat) is loaded, since [`newfloat`](https://ctan.org/pkg/newfloat) is compatible with it.

While no longer mentioned in the [current `newfloat` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/newfloat.pdf), an [older version](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/doc/texlive-doc/latex/caption/newfloat.pdf) discussed `newfloat`'s implementation details. Section 5.10.1 outlines the compatibility of [`newfloat`](https://ctan.org/pkg/newfloat) with [`float`](https://ctan.org/pkg/float), stating in part:

> If the `float` package is used we fill up `\float@exts` with our file extensions, too. Since this list will be used for inserting chapters gaps we only add the ones which are configured for chapters gaps on.

[`newfloat`](https://ctan.org/pkg/newfloat) may not replace [`float`](https://ctan.org/pkg/float) from the perspective of the [`algorithm`](https://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) package, so it is likely best to load it as well.

Therefore, you can simply do the following:

```
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[newfloat=true]{minted}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{algorithm}
```

Comment: I wonder why the package author removed this compatibility clause in the newer version of the manual. Worst case (shudder) this is not true anymore. I guess it is out of the scope of this answer anyway. Maybe other experts (I think ```newfloat``` author is a strong contributor here) may take notice and answer this in the future. Thank you for your sustained efforts in providing a helpful and concise answer.

Comment: @Krishna I was wondering that as well. But I think all of that is still current. It appears merely that all implementation details were removed from the current manual. All of section 5, dedicated to discussing support of other packages, is no longer present. My pleasure—glad that I was able to help!

Comment: Since most users are not interested in the implementation, I process the file newfloat.dtx with \OnlyDescription to get newfloat.pdf which is uploaded to CTAN. But everyone is free to process newfloat.dtx without it to get the documentation including the implementation part. So nothing has been removed in the manual (at least not in the source code of it), and the compatibility clause is still true. BTW: The process of "the author may take notice" could be speed-up by inserting @AxelSommerfeldt in the answer/comment, or by sending me an e-mail ;-) My e-mail address could be find in the README.